# How can I print the content of a HTML input field multiple times using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input field and a button 
I write a name in the input field push the button and it writes under the input field the name every time you push the button it adds under the previous name the next name

jquery code

```
var naam = new array["registration:"];

    $(document).register(function(){
        $("#confirm").click(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < naam.length; i++) {
            naam.push('<span>' + "inName"+ '</span>')
        }
        })


    });
```

html code

```
<p>Please enter your name below.</p>
    <span id="name">Name:</span><input type="text" id="inName"><button id="confirm">Confirm</button>

    <p id="registration"></p>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, or what is not working?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I made an edit to his question's title. I think it was : "How can I print the content of a HTML input field multiple time using jQuery?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your trying to Achieve this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6123j8sm/2/)

**HTML**

```
<p>Please enter your name below.</p>
    <span id="name">Name:</span><input type="text" id="inName"><button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
<ul id="registration"></ul>
```

**Script**

```
 $('#confirm').click(function(){  
   if($('#inName').val() != ""){
     $('#registration').prepend('<li>'+ $('#inName').val() +'</li>'); 
     $('#inName').val("");
   }
});
```

Comment: yeah that's it but i need registrated above the first name

Comment: it works in the fiddle but if i put in sublimetext and rn it in chrome it doesn't do it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example showing keeping a log of names entered in an array and also inserting those names each time under the text field.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/kzws8fok/

JS:

```
var registeredNames = [];

$('#confirm').on('click',
    function () {
        inName = $('#inName');
        var newName = inName.val();
        registeredNames.push(newName);
        $('#registration').append('<div>' + newName + '</div>');
        inName.val('');
        $('#currentArray').text(JSON.stringify(registeredNames));
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<p>Please enter your name below.</p> <span id="name">Name:</span>
<input type="text" id="inName">
<button type="button" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
<p id="registration"></p>
<div id="currentArray"></div>
```